# site unavailable after install and reboot and plonectl start

Tags: linux, plone, ubuntu-10.04, restart

Ubuntu 10.04 system. new Plone install, went fine and created some content, everything seemed fine.  New kernel update and a reboot later, Plone is running but will not present any pages to a browser.  In fact, a browser attempt just times out.  I can telnet to the port 8080 on the system and send an HTTP get by hand and nothing comes back.  The log file for client1 in a zeo install keeps repeating:

```
2011-08-10T16:59:57 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Wed Aug 10 16:59:57 2011
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8080
------
2011-08-10T16:59:57 INFO Zope Set effective user to "plone"
------
2011-08-10T17:00:02 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage ClientStorage (pid=24596) created RW/normal for storage: '1'
------
2011-08-10T17:00:02 INFO ZEO.cache created temporary cache file '<fdopen>'
------
2011-08-10T17:00:02 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Testing connection <ManagedClientConnection ('127.0.0.1', 8100)>
------
2011-08-10T17:00:02 INFO ZEO.zrpc.Connection(C) (127.0.0.1:8100) received handshake 'Z3101'
------
2011-08-10T17:00:02 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Server authentication protocol None
------
2011-08-10T17:00:02 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Connected to storage: ('dns', 8100)
------
2011-08-10T17:00:02 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage No verification necessary -- empty cache
------
2011-08-10T17:00:22 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Wed Aug 10 17:00:22 2011
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8080
```

I haven't been able to find any other info on what is causing this, nor can I find any documentation on debugging a Plone install.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Checked your file ownership and permissions? Make sure all the daemon processes — including zeo — can find and write to log and data files. Also, check the zeo log as well as the client log.

Answer (score 3):

Forgive the aborted answer, misread the log snippet.  The repeated log entries you're seeing are what you'd expect to see from repeated restarts.  Are you repeatedly restarting the instance?  If not, then in it seems your instance is restarting on it's own.  Shut down the instance and start it using "bin/instance fg" and see if that gives you more information.

Comment: I'm not restarting it manually, it's restarting itself and leaving no log trace that I can find. 

I'm trying to run a zeocluster.  But doing a bin/zeoserver fg results in 
root@dns:/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster# bin/zeoserver fg
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/parts/zeoserver/bin/runzeo
and then nothing else.

Comment: My answer suggested that you stop the *instance*, not the ZEO server, and start the instance in debug mode to see what's happening.  Try this: shut everything down, start the zeoserver, then start the instance in foreground/debug-mode with the "fg" command and see if that tells you more.

Comment: Oh, I believe you mean the clients to the zeoserver, Client1 and Client2.  I'll try that, thanks again.

Comment: Awesome troubleshooting advice. In my case the error was: ImportError: libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I resolved this (Ubuntu) by running apt-get install libxslt1.1 .